# Double addition in hive returns different precision every time

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to sum up a column of double type in hive. However the result is inconsistent. I am getting value like `136.0021` as output and on rerunning I am getting value as `136.0017`. I can understand that we cant expect precision  with double values. But my output is to be saved in hive table where the column is configured as double type.

Is there any approach to resolve this precision issue without updating column data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cast double values to decimal before performing addition. After addition I then cast result back to double and put it in hdfs.